# Test a method returning a PageReference in Salesforce

Tags: testing, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I have a method in the controller

```
    public PageReference add() {
              insert technology;
              return null;
            }
```

`technology` is a custom object .It has its own getters and setters.How do I test this method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 public static testMethod void testMyController() {


   PageReference pageRef = Page.yourPageName;

   Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

   MyController controller = new MyController();
   controller.add();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In test class You had to initialize Your controler and call this method:

```
static testMethod void test(){
    YourController contr = new YourController();
    contr.add();
}
```

Hope that helps.